# Laravel 4 Eloquent ORM select where - array as parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is solution for this in Eloquent ORM?

I have array with parents idetifiers:

```
Array ( [0] => 87,  [1] => 65, ... )
```

And i want select table PRODUCTS where parent_id column = any id in array

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Fluent:

```
DB::table('PRODUCTS')->whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids)->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
Product::whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids)->get();
```

Comment: FWIW, also in the Eloquent example you need to `get()` the results:

`Product::whereIn('parent_id', $parent_ids)->get();`

Answer (score 24):

Your array must be like this :

```
$array = array(87, 65, "etc");
Product::whereIn('parent_id', $array)->get();
```

or

```
Product::whereIn('parent_id', array(87, 65, "etc"))->get();
```