# Retrieve results based on condition of relation laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I achieve the following with Laravel.

I have a table Products, which has a oneToMany relationship with ProductSizes - product sizes holds sizes related to a product.

I'm trying to do a query where - I get all products, where productSizes has a size of say 'Medium'.

I looked at using 'With' but this just returns an object with the overall product listing, with only those sizes....

I want to actually only bring back products that specifically only have a value of 'Medium' within the size column of the ProductSizes table.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605693/laravel-4-eloquent-orm-select-where-array-as-parameter) might answer your question. Grab your unique product IDs from the productSizes table where the size is medium, then use that for a query on your products table where the ID is in your result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$medium_product_ids = ProductSizes::where('size_name', '=', 'medium')->distinct()->get(array('product_id'));
$products = Products::whereIn('product_id',$medium_product_ids)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a join:

```
Product::join('product_sizes', 'product_sizes.id', '=', 'products.product_size_id')
    ->where('size_name' = 'medium')
    ->get();
```

Using 'with' eager loads the relationship after the query has run so you can't constrain using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think it should get products with only medium size:

```
Products::leftJoin('ProductSizes', 'products.id', '=', 'ProductSizes.product_id')
    ->groupBy('products.id')
    ->having(DB::raw('count(*) = 1 and size="Medium"'))
    ->get();
```