# Does Laravel/Eloquent Support "IN" Queries?

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent

Does Laravel's ORM support `IN` queries?

That is, in plain old SQL I can write

```
select * from students where id IN (3503, 3504);
```

and the query returns two rows.  Does Laravel's ORM support this sort of syntax with parameterized queries?  I've tried

```
$students = Student::whereRaw('id IN (?)',['3503, 3504'])->get();
$students = Student::where('id','in','3503,3504')->get();
$students = Student::where('id','in',['3503,3504'])->get();
```

but nothing seems to work.  Laravel 4.2, if it matters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605693/laravel-4-eloquent-orm-select-where-array-as-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it does:

```
$students = Student::whereIn('id',['3503','3504'])->get();
```