# MySql multiple times Where in Condition if possible

Tags: mysql

i am Performing the `MySQL query with Where In conditions`.

Here is my Query.

The query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (44,44,33,44,33,0);
```

**Query showing my correct result, no problem at all, 
but what i want to do is Can we Divide all the id with the individual conditions ?**

Or can a query has multiple `Where In` for a `single column`? 
like

**SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (44)
AND id IN (45)
AND id IN (46);**

like this.

**Is that possible ? ?**

My query code for performing the query, its in Laravel.

```
$films = Film::with('genre')->with('languages')->with('likes')->with('comments')->with('likedBy');

        if(Input::get('sort')){
            $sort = Input::get('sort');
            switch ($sort){
                case 'old_new':
                    $films = $films->orderBy('created_at', 'asc');
                    break;
                case 'new_old':
                    $films = $films->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                    break;
                case 'views':
//                    $films = DB::table('films')
//                        ->leftJoin('film_views', 'films.id', '=', 'film_views.film_id')
//                        ->select(DB::raw('films.*, count(film_views.film_id) as views'))
//                        ->groupBy('films.id')
//                        ->orderBy('views' , 'desc')
//                        ;

                    $films = $films
                        ->leftJoin('film_views', 'films.id', '=', 'film_views.film_id')
                        ->select(DB::raw('films.*, count(film_views.film_id) as views'))
                        //->whereBetween('created_at', [$this->first_day_of_search, $this->final_day_of_search])
                        ->groupBy('films.id')
                        ->orderBy('views' , 'desc')
                    ;

                    break;
                case 'likes':
                    $films = $films
                        ->leftJoin('film_likes', 'films.id', '=', 'film_likes.film_id')
                        ->select(DB::raw('films.*, count(film_likes.film_id) as likes'))
                        ->groupBy('films.id')
                        ->orderBy('likes' , 'desc')
                       ;
                    break;
            }


        }
        if(Input::get('filter')) {
            $jsonFilter = Input::get('filter');
            $filters = json_decode($jsonFilter);

            foreach ($filters as $filter => $value){
                switch ($filter){
                    case "genre":
                        if($value){
                            $films = $films->whereHas('genre', function ($query) use($value) {
                                $query->whereIn('genre_id', $value);
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    case "cert":
                       if($value){
                           $films = $films->whereIn('cert', $value);
                       }
                        break;
                    case "country":
                        if($value){
                            $films = $films->whereIn('country', $value);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "lang":
                       if($value){
                           $films = $films->whereHas('languages', function ($query) use($value) {
                               $query->whereIn('language_id', $value);
                           });
                       }
                        break;
                }
            }


        }



        $films = $films->paginate(5);

        return parent::api_response($films->toArray(), true, ['return' => 'all films'], 200);
```

Comment: you can have a custom `order by`. You can create a trailing column that has a value based on id ranges (like segments) and use that column for the custom.

Comment: @Drew  , actually i have to put all the Ids in foreach and then making a query , dont want comma separated values for where In condition,

Comment: no, I referred to the `order by` as custom ... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9378613

Comment: So, your trailing column could be in a `case when`

Comment: @Drew Good evening, and you should be answering more.

Comment: miseur how goes it

Comment: In that case you have to use OR =>SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID IN(1) OR ID IN (2);

Comment: but from the performance point it is not a good way

Comment: Why in the earth you want multiple `IN` clause for the same field??? Makes no sense, completely unnecessary (unless you passed the limit clause elements configured, which given your sample it is not the case).

Comment: @JorgeCampos i know it does not make any sense but i am finding any alternate solution , because my all the conditions are in foreach loop

Comment: Show your `foreach` code and you will see in no time a much better version of what you think you should do as an answer.

Comment: So just convert each case into an array and pass it to the filter like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22221454/460557

Comment: but what about the other filters.

Comment: What about it? You have to convert each of your cases statements into arrays, so you would have an array of genre, one of cert, one of country and so on, then you would need just an if statement to see if those arrays aren't empty to add the each filter.

Comment: At this point `foreach ($filters as $filter => $value)` you already have the arrays you just need to use it

Comment: I'm going to sleep now. Hope some one show you how to do it. It is late at my end. Wish you good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post an answer if for no other reason than amusement.  I believe that a `WHERE IN` clause is internally converted into a series of equality onditions separated by `OR`.  So your original query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (44,44,33,44,33,0)
```

would be internally converted to this

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 44 OR id = 44 OR id = 33 OR id = 44 OR
                          id = 33 OR id = 0
```

So having a single number for your `IN` clause would be equivalent to a single equality condition.

By the way, you have the same numbers appearing multiple times, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Any other way except this. ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple `WHERE IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (44) OR id IN (45) OR id IN (46);
```

This is correct.

However I don't understand why you want to do this because this is low in performance compared to having one IN

Comment: This is about as ridiculous as it gets.

Comment: Sorry didnt get you

Comment: I really should remove my downvote. The problem is the question, not this so much. But it is still ridiculous.

Comment: Let's say the `in` clause was 92 items. What might it look like? And why would put the db engine thru that?

Comment: @Drew: As i saw he asked "can a query has multiple Where In for a single column" I said yes, thats all

Comment: Yeah, but you are supposed to be the `mysql` guru here. And you need to decipher question gibberish and steer it in the right direction. Why would anyone code like that, when it  clogs the parser down? Why not just tack a hundred `and 1=1` onto the end for good effect.

Comment: @drew: Ya this is pointless. I know. But he might have some sets of ids where it comes from separate queries or something, that need to be added in separate IN s

Comment: That would be even worse.

Comment: Downvote removed. No fault of yours the thing is so unclear.